# How to access localhost from Genymotion 2.6.0?

Tags: android, web-services

```
http://10.0.3.2/script.php
```

The given url is not working for me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd, type ipconfig and look for your PC IPv4, copy the IP address and paste it in the URL so the url will look like

```
String url = "http://IPV4Address:8888/index.php";
```

Comment: I used it but still not working, Genymotion shows me that "unfortunately your app stopped working" while there is no error in app and my php script as well

Comment: OK try the port 8080 instead of 8888. Or instead of the PC IP try 10.0.3.2.